# dynamically generating checkbox list from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, checkboxlist

I'm dynamically generating a list of checkboxes based on the contents of json data:

Format of tempfairway: 
`[{"FairWay":"A"},{"FairWay":"B"}, {"FairWay":"C"}, {"FairWay":"D"}]`

```
var topics = tempfairway;
var topicContainer = $('ul#fairway_list');
$.each(topics, function (iteration, item) { topicContainer.append(
$(document.createElement("li")).append(
$(document.createElement("input")).attr({
        id: 'topicFilter-' + item,
        name: item, 
        value: item,
        type: 'checkbox',
        checked: true
        })
        //onclick
        .click(function (event) {
         var cbox = $(this)[0];
         alert(cbox.value);
         })
).append(
$(document.createElement('label')).attr({
'for': 'topicFilter' + '-' + item
}).text(item)
   )
     )
});
```

The checkboxes generate fine with the correct number but i'm getting [object Object] instead of the name of the fairway.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Couple of more questions to add to this:
-What if i wanted to display ONLY unique values in tempfairway?
-.Click is set to get the value of that single checkbox, what if i want to iterate through all the checkboxes and get the value of all the ones that were selected in the case that the user unselected any of them?

Comment: Please use common statements terminated with semicolons. Very long chained calls might be hip, but they are very hard to debug and maintain (as you're no doubt discovering). And `$(this)[0]` is equivalent (though vastly more compute intensive) to just plain `this`.

Comment: `item` is an object. You are setting `value: item`. The default representation of objects is `[object Object]`. You probable want `value: item.FairWay` (maybe also for your other `item` uses. Also: `$(document.createElement("input"))` `->` `$('<input />')`

Comment: Thank you for the help. The item.FairWay solved the problem. Also, I'm taking all the input into better, cleaner code.

Now one more question, what if i wanted to select only distinct values from this result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
> $.each(topics, function (iteration, item) {
```

item is an object like `{"FairWay":"A"}`, so where you have:

```
> .text(item)
```

you probably want:

```
 .text(item.FairWay)
```

and similarly for other uses of `item`. Or you could store the value in a variable and use that:

```
var fairwayName = item.FairWay;
...
.text(fairwayName);
```

Comment: in addition if you want the term `FairWay` converting the object to array `["FairWay","A"]` at server would help or `{"name":"FairWay", "value":"A"}` as object